# Angular / Ionic get changes done on ion-toggle on parent component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a toggle button on a child component of my Ionic/Angular project.

In the child component I have:

```
<ion-buttons slot="end">
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="enabled" (ionChange)="toggleEnabled()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-buttons>
```

In the parent component I have:

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

In the parent .ts:

```
enable: boolean = false;

toggleEnabled() {
    // code here executed when the child toggle button is changed.
}
```

How can I leave the ion-toggle button in the child component but get changes and execute toggleEnabled() which is on the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the Output into your child class.

Documentation about this: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

In **Angular**

.ts

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

class ChildComponent {
  @Output() outputName = new EventEmitter<any>();
public enabled: boolean; // I guess 'enabled' is a boolean into the child's .ts

enableButton(): void {
  this.outputName.emit(this.enabled); // here you put the output from child to parent 
}


}
```

.html

```
<ion-buttons slot="end">
    <ion-toggle (click)="enableButton()" [(ngModel)]="enabled"></ion-toggle>
</ion-buttons>
```

then you will include into parent's HTML file the child element like this:

```
<child-component (outputName)="toggleEnabled($event)"></child-component>
```

Parent's .ts

```
toggleEnabled(isEnabled: boolean): void {

// do something with 'enabled' data

}
```

Comment: Feel like this answer is missing some crucial steps to get event emitter to work properly. I advise to revise.

Comment: I didn't include the import part because it's not specified if it's angular or ionic and there are different ways to do so. But i'll edit that thanks

Comment: I need to also pass the enabled status to the parent component

Comment: Ok sorry, I'll edit that for you

Comment: @DiegoLai I was refering to your answer partially working, IE only declaring eventemitter and setting it in template and omitted the actual logic that emits values to the parent. But i see you've edited in this now, good!

Comment: @Tommi yeah you did good, I wanted to give an idea about how to solve this but this wasn't enough helpful even for other users with this problem so I hope now is more clear for everyone. The boolean here is very specific to this problem but can be transform to object/other variable if someone needs that!